Example of a function that is strongly quasi-convex but not strongly convex
I am reading this paper, and there's a notion of strong quasi-convexity defined as such: $$\forall x \in \Bbb R ^d, \quad f(x^*)\geq f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x),x^*-x \rangle+ \frac{\mu}{2} \left\lVert x^*-x\right\lVert^2  $$
The definition is pretty straightforward as it requires to strong convexity condition to hold only for $y=x^*$. The strong convexity implies the uniqueness of minimum, but apparently strong quasi-convexity (defined above) does not. Why? And can anyone give me an example of a function that is strongly quasi-convex but not strongly convex?

I think we need to clarify the definition of strong quasi-convexity.
In the paper you provided, it showed that strong quasi-convexity was introduced in this paper (Definition $1$ in Section $3.1$), here we quote the definition:

A function $f$ is strongly quasi-convex on set $X$ if there is $\mu>0$ such that
$$f(x^*)\geq f(x)+\langle\nabla f(x),x^*-x\rangle+\frac\mu2\|x-x^*\|^2\quad \forall x\in X,$$
where $x^*\in\text{argmin}_{u\in X^*}\|x-u\|$ and $X^*=\text{argmin}_{u\in X}f(u)$.

In other words, given any $x\in X$, the minimizer $x^*$ is chosen such that $\|x-x^*\|\leq\|x-u\|$ for all other minimizers $u$. This means we only vary $x\in X$ and choose $x^*$ based on $x$, whereas for strong convexity both $x$ and $x^*$ can vary independently. For comparison, here is the definition of strong convexity:

A function $f$ is strongly convex on set $X$ if there is $\mu>0$ such that
$$f(x^*)\geq f(x)+\langle\nabla f(x),x^*-x\rangle+\frac\mu2\|x-x^*\|^2\quad \forall x,x^*\in X.$$

By the above definitions, quasi-strong convexity does not imply the uniqueness of minimizers. For example, consider the space $X=[0,\infty)$ and
$$f(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}\ 0&\text{if}\ \ 0\leq x<1,\\\ (x-1)^2&\text{if}\ \ x\geq1.\end{matrix}\right.$$
Then $f$ is not strongly convex (consider $x=1/2,x^*=1$), but it is strongly quasi-convex (for $\mu=2$ choose $x^*=x$ if $x\in[0,1]$ or $x^*=1$ if $x>1$). This shows strong quasi-convex cannot guarantee the uniqueness of minimizers.

@saaleh Thank you, but does this answer your question? I mean your definition seems a little different from the one I got from the original paper.
